# SQL Server 2008 connection with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

No matter what I try I keep getting the following error when I try to run a simple select query to the database I created (I've run the exact query in the Management studio and it works fine and the login used is in the sysadmin group):

> {"Cannot open database \"Test\" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.\r\nLogin failed for user
>   'JackLarson'."}   System.SystemException
>   {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

My connection string is:

> Data Source=.\MPIT_TEST;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated
>   Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True

Comment: What credentials are you using to connect to the database in SSMS?  And what credentials is your C# running under?

Comment: Could you post the query from your code? Error message makes me wonder something..

Comment: Sir Crispalot: I'm not sure how to check the credentials. From the error message I thought it was using my Windows login.

David W: The query is "SELECT * FROM dbo.tblMPINum"

Comment: For what it's worth, user instances are deprecated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx

Comment: Is your database called Test or Test_MPITRACKER? So confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set your server name in your connection string
if your servername is SERVERSQLCOMPUTER your connection string will be:

```
Data Source=SERVERSQLCOMPUTER \MPIT_TEST;Initial Catalog=[Test_MPITRACKER];Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

Moreover, always specify server name to be able to use your application on every computer in network entreprise (servername\serverinstance is an absolute path) 
.\serverinstance means that your application is on the same computer than your Sql server

Comment: Thanks @Hassan Boutougha Changing it to include the specific server name fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the error message. It says it cannot find database named *Test* although you specified *Test_MPITRACKER* in the connection string. It looks like there is an issue when you have a database with undescore `_` character in its name.

The easiest way would be to remove the undescore from the name of the database.

If you want to use database name with the underscore character, try to wrap it with square brackets, so it looks like this:

```
Data Source=.\MPIT_TEST;Initial Catalog=[Test_MPITRACKER];Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

However, I haven't tested this solution, it's based on information found here: [Database created in SQL Server Management Studios cannot be found by Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677217/database-created-in-sql-management-studios-cannot-be-found-by-visual-studio-2010).

**EDIT**

According to the conversation in the comments this is not the cause of the issue in this case.

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo. My boss is strict about the possibility of anything specific about our system being posted online. The database it can't find is the same one that is called in the connection string

Comment: I tried removing the underscore but I still get the same error

Comment: Try to create a new SQL user, map him to `Test_MPITRACKER` database, enable SQL authentication and use his credentials in the connection string. To verify if the access for this user is ok, make sure you can log with those credentials with SQL Management Studio. This could give some clues to what the problem is. Also try to remove `User Instance` from the connection string, as it seems to be deprecated (as mentioned in another comment).

Comment: How do I enable SQL authentication?

Comment: @Donnachaidh have you searched? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

Comment: From what I can find I need the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration tool installed to allow SQL Server Authentication and all of the IT people (who are the only ones with admin privileges) have left for the weekend.

Comment: Where did you "find" this information? This is a simple change in Management Studio and then a server restart. You don't need the Surface Area Configuration tool for this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1TpYY.png

Comment: I see the issue is resolved, but just to let you know: to enable SQL authentication in SQL Server Management Studio connect to the server, right-click on the server, click **Properties** and in the **Security** tab select **SQL Authentication and Windows Authentication mode**. It's described here: http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/06/sql-server-authentication-enabling.html.