# Use database objects created in SQL Server Management Studio in Visual Studio instead

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssms

I am building a website using ASP.NET development.

I performed all my database tasks (tables, user-defined functions, stored procedures) using SQL Server Management Studio.

Now, I would like to continue to use the database stuff I have created for my website in Visual Studio. How do I do that?

To give an example, I have created a stored procedure (that works with some tables and scalar valued function) in SSMS that requires a user input for start and end date.

In Visual Studio, I have created a webpage that asks the user for the start and end date. I would now like to "transfer" the above mentioned stored procedure (together with the tables and scalar valued functions) to Visual Studio so that I can use the user input as query to the stored procedure.

I am using the following: Visual Studio 2010, SSMS 2008

Answer (score 0):

As per your explanation I understand you want to create webpage that intract with a SQL Server database, below are the one example in this portal itself to connect to SQL Server from Visual studio with a stored procedure.

[Database created in SQL Server Management Studios cannot be found by Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677217/database-created-in-sql-management-studios-cannot-be-found-by-visual-studio-2010?rq=1)

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedures-using-ASPNet-Example.aspx

Let me know your comment if I can be of more help to you.